# ExceptionInInitializerError in Android Library

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting `ExceptionInInitializerError`, and then `NoClassDefFoundError`, from an android networking library.

https://github.com/bclymer/bc-rest-client/blob/master/src/com/bclymer/rest/BcRestClient.java

That's the file that is causing the exceptions to be thrown, but as you can see the class it can't find, `com/bclymer/rest/BcRestClient$DownloadWebSourceTask`, is right below the method `performRequest`. From what I read `ExceptionInInitializerError` will cause `NoClassDefFoundError` to be thrown, but I can't find any reason that the class couldn't initialize correctly.

This exception is thrown rarely also, it's happened 21 times to 7 users, out of ~10,000 uses of this same networking library, and ~4,000 from the same method in MusicService.

```
Fatal Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
com/bclymer/rest/BcRestClient$DownloadWebSourceTask

BcRestClient.java line 140
com.bclymer.rest.BcRestClient.performRequest
BcRestClient.java line 139
com.bclymer.rest.BcRestClient.access$3
BcRestClient.java line 415
com.bclymer.rest.BcRestClient$Builder.executeAsync
MusicService.java line 436
com.xxx.xxx.media.MusicService$5.run
ThreadPoolExecutor.java line 1076
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
Thread.java line 856
java.lang.Thread.run
```

I'm making the request to the library with this:

```
new BcRestClient.Builder("http://www.validurl.com", RequestType.GET)
            .setCastClass(SetResponse.class)
            .setRestClientCallback(new BcRestClientCallback<SetResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onPreExecute() {

                }
                @Override
                public void onPostExecute() {

                }
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(BcRestClientResponse<SetResponse> response) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(BcRestClientResponse<SetResponse> response) {

                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

If you need any more code let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer, I was also getting a `RuntimeException` with the message

`Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

The library is creating an AsyncTask, which needs to be created on the UI thread.

100% of these crashes (70 so far) happened pre-jellybean, which as AsyncTask.java says

`The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN.`

Hopefully this will help somebody else!